# The server is not operational

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

This is the code I'm using to connecting to LDAP

```
 using (DirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", this.Host, ServerName)))
        {
            DirEntry.RefreshCache();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
            {
                DirEntry.Username = UserName;
                DirEntry.Password = PassWord;
            }
            if (DirEntry.Properties.Contains("objectGUID"))
            {
                byte[] guiddatet = (byte[])DirEntry.Properties["objectGUID"].Value;
                return new Guid(guiddatet);
            }
```

I get "The server is not operational" error message when I run the code.

Can someone please tell me where I'm doing it wrong.
And is there anyway to replace the above code with direct LDAP query.

Comment: What **values** do you have in `this.Host` and `ServerName` ?? What does your complete LDAP string look like that you use to create that `DirectoryEntry`?

Comment: This is how my LDAP string looks like:  LDAP://xyz.sdomain.com/CN=xyz,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=sdomain,DC=com

Comment: And on **which line exactly** does this error happen when you debug through?

Comment: this.host = "xyz.sdomain.com"  and servername = "CN=xyz,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site,CN=Sites,CN=Confi‌​guration,DC=sdomain,DC=com"

Comment: Are you able to telnet to the LDAP server on port 389 from the machine the code is running on? Have you tried replacing the host name with an IP address?

Comment: I did check "telnet <LDAP> 389" and its running. Did not replace the host name with an IP address.

Comment: in my case [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/742488/computers-point-to-dc-in-wrong-site) was my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try breaking this into separate parts, so it's easier to manage the logic, and easier to locate where your errors are occurring. I usually go with the following approach in this situation :

- Create an `LdapConnection` object so you can set the options you need
- Setup a `NetworkCredential` instance with an administrative username and password
- Bind to the directory with the user so you can issue a direct LDAP query
- Return a `SearchResultEntry` so you can process the properties

You have a few options to help you accomplish this, but I'd try something like this :

```
//Delcare your Network Credential with the administrative Username, Password, and your active directory domain
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

//Create a directory identifier and connection, 
var ldapidentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(serverName, port, false, false);
var ldapconn = new LdapConnection(ldapidentifier, credentials);
```

Next, make sure you're setting the right `AuthType` for your particular instance. Since you're connecting over port 389, just use `AuthType.Basic`.

```
ldapconn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
```

As you had asked, there is a very easy way to setup a direct LDAP query using this approach. I'm assuming you're searching by `sAMAccountName`, but you can modify this as needed :

```
string ldapFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(&(sAMAccountName={{UserYouAreTryingToFind}})))";
```

Now we just have to setup the search request, and send it accordingly :

```
//Send the search request with our delimited attribute list
var getUserRequest = new SearchRequest(domain, ldapFilter, SearchScope.Subtree, AttributeList)
                                     {SizeLimit = 1};

//Suppress any refferal creation from happening during the search
var SearchControl = new SearchOptionsControl(SearchOption.DomainScope);
getUserRequest.Controls.Add(SearchControl);
var userResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapconn.SendRequest(getUserRequest);

//This is where I load up the entry I've located, 
SearchResultEntry ResultEntry = userResponse.Entries[0];
```

That should return the user you've queried for, along with any properties you've put into `AttributeList`. In this context, `AttributeList` is just a string array (`string[]`) of property names - in your case you'll want to add one called "objectGUID".

As for reading the properties on the `SearchResultEntry`, you can do exactly what you had originally :

```
 if(ResultEntry.Attributes.Contains("objectGUID"))
 {
     // do some stuff here
 }
```

That should help get you going in the right direction.

Also, if you don't already have a copy of [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), I highly suggest you download it - it will be invaluable in diagnosing connection issues with active directory.